# Java. Simulating users periodical actions (Threads, ExecutorService)

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I'd like to make a java standalone app, that simulates users periodically making post requests to a server.

I'm planning on using Retrofit for making the http requests and ExecutorService to control the "users" and schedule the tasks(post requests). The idea is that I don't want to register the **same** task 
to be repeated over and over, but at regular intervals for each user, a new task to be done.

Let me give you an example:

There are 3 users(|) and each makes a post request every 10 seconds(-----) with a random initial delay (**). Note that the tasks are different.

|**task1-----task11-----task111-----task1111....
|******task2-----task22-----task222-----task2222....
|****task3-----task33-----task333-----task3333....

I know that tools such as ApacheJMeter already do that, but they can
 be difficult to set up and I'm interested in building my own from scratch.

What would be a professional and elegant way of achieving this?

Thank you in advance,
Alexander

Comment: _What would be a professional and elegant way of achieving this?_ Using the right tool for the job. For example Apache JMeter.

Comment: Apache Jmeter would be best! Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If you want scheduling, you should consider using a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of a "plain" `ExecutorService`

Comment: @BoristheSpider and SMA, it's a personal project and I'm interested into working a little with threads/actors.
fge from my understanding ScheduledExecutorService schedules the **same** thing to be called over and over, and that's not exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea would be to create USERS * threads whose run() method would look similar to

```
void run() {
     while(1) {
          doStuff();
          sleep(SECONDS * 1000);
     }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the proper approach